# 24v motor controlled by weather

Tags: remote, home-automation

I would like to control a 24v motor with the Raspberry Pi, using pulses. The script to turn the motor on should only be ran weather dependent. So I would like the Pi to constantly check weather, or wait for a weather alert, and then act on the correct weather forecast, and discard the rest.

Comment: It would be great to see anything you have coded thus far, and I think it is advisable to give a little more detail on your situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can [control a motor](http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/controlling-dc-motors-using-python-with-a-raspberry-pi--cms-20051) using the GPIO pins, however the motor will need it's own power supply. As for sensing the weather, you will need appropriate sensors, which again you can monitor through the GPIO pins. People have built [weather stations out of a Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/school-weather-station-project/) before. If you just want to wait for a weather alert, the Raspberry Pi 3 B has onboard WiFi, which you can use to check weather sites regularly, and you can even automate that task.